# In Firebase Functions, would data be cached if 2 users hit the same instance?

Tags: express, caching, google-cloud-functions

Let's imagine I have the following code which authenticates a user and then caches it so the next request can go faster without re-authenticating the user.

```js
export const app = express();

let currentUser: User | undefined = undefined;

export function authenticateUser(
  req: express.Request,
  res: express.Response,
  next: express.NextFunction
) {
  if(!currentUser) {
    currentUser = authenticateUser();
  }
  next();
}

app.get("/", authenticateUser, async (_req, res) => {
  send(`Hello, ${currentUser.name}!`);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  debug(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
export const myfunction = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

In this code, I'm expecting that the same user will do the the first request, which loads the information and then performs another request which uses the cached information. Now, I'm worried whether this would be a problem if I have 2 users hitting the same instance almost at same time and I'll have this problem:

| Request from | Output |
| --- | --- |
| User A | Hello, User A! |
| User B | Hello, User A! |

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible that 2 users could hit the same instance?
2. If so, will the cached information be cleaned up somehow by Firebase or it'll stay?
3. If information will be cached, how can I solve this? I think my options could be:

   1. Make sure information is cleaned if the coming user is different
   2. Configure somehow cloud functions to ensure only exists one instance per user. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, instances may be re-used for multiple calls.
2. Your script will NOT be reloaded between these calls, so `currentUser` will have the same value you gave it before.
3. It depends on how you handle the authentication, but the common approach would be to pass the ID token from the client to the Cloud Function, and [decode and verify it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) there. For an example of this, see this [repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/Node-1st-gen/authorized-https-endpoint).

Comment: Thanks! I also ended up asking chatGPT :P indeed you're right, I have made my server calls stateless so I don't have unexpected behaviors between calls. The downside that I was trying to avoid is to call stuff from the DB each time a call happens as I want to my service to be as efficient as possible. Storing everything in the ID token seems not to be the right approach. Any suggestion on how to cache objects data in the client using firebase? I'd naturally think of cookies but firebase only allows _session